# I want to use a US states map an color each state with an unique color in R using ggplot. How is this possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, spatial

```
all_states <- map_data("state")
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_polygon( data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),colour="white", fill="grey30" )
p
```

*The code is above, also I want to use geom_map instead of geom_polygon.In the above code I am only able to color the states grey or any other color.What I want is an unique color for each state*

Comment: so, what's the problem, what have you tried, what has worked, what has not? We're not a free code-writing service, I'm afraid!

Comment: You wanna have `colour` in `aes()` if you want to assign an unique color to each state. But I am not sure if using more than seven colors allows people to recognize all colors.

Comment: exactly,so here what I need is a unique color for each state. Any color pallete is available that contains around 50 colours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your own palette, find a list of R colors and create a concatenated list of all of the colors. You need to make sure that you have levels for each state to assign the colors.

If you want to assign them yourself to states so that similar colors are no near each other, you can assign a color to a state by the code or name in your data frame.

```
p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("New York" = "#E08214", "New Jersey" = "#E08214", "New Hampshire" = "#336699"))
```

This gives you control over how the colors are displayed.